# outer position css to wrap fixed content?

Tags: html, css

I want to develop a mobile frame to wrap the content of my site if it's mobile, but I'm having issue on the css. I put a wrapper but the header and footer is position fixed, the wrapper doesn't seem to have any effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/ymo5xo4m/

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#mobile-frame {
  border: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='mobile-frame'>
  <header>header</header>
  <content>body content abc</content>
  <footer>copyright 2018</footer>
</div>
```

Should I put the mobile-wrapper as the same level and use position absolute?

Comment: Why not alter the `header`/`footer` css when in mobile so that they are not `position:fixed` ?

Comment: I'm not sure - you want to remove the position: fixed on mobile?

Comment: Would be appreciated if you could rate or comment if thats the answer you wanted.

Comment: Pretty unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your approach:

- Why are you wrapping the header and footer in a wrapper? And you should read up of `position:fixed`. They take absolute position on the viewport without scrolling affecting them. If you want a border around the entire content you should rather fix the wrapper.

> I'd say this approach is wrong though. And you should not wrap your fixed elements inside a wrapper which you are placing your body contents in. Thus, fix your header and footer outside the wrapper and encapsulate the content within the wrapper between them.

- Your shorthand syntax for border is incorrect. You have to use the syntax as: `border:5px solid black;` (according to your styling and color).

Here's a demonstration if this is what you intended:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#mobile-frame {
  height:100vh;
  z-index:1;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='mobile-frame'>
  <header>header</header>
  <content>body content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abccontent abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abcbody content abc</content>
  <footer>copyright 2018</footer>
</div>
```